# Upgrade openssl from 0.9 to 1.0 on PHP running on IIS

Tags: php, ssl, iis, php-openssl

We've recently come across a problem connecting to an API because it has updated its system to only accept requests which are sent using TLS 1.2. Upon research, I found out that to use TLS 1.2, you have to have OpenSSL 1.0 as an extension in your PHP install. The PHP (ver 5.3.8) we have running on IIS has OpenSSL 0.9. Is there a way to upgrade OpenSSL to 1.0 without upgrading PHP?

Comment: NO, there is no way to upgrade from OpenSSL 0.9.8 to OpenSSL 1.0.x or OpenSSL 1.1.x. They ***are not*** binary compatible. Also, you should use OpenSSL 1.0.2 or OpenSSL 1.1.0. All the others, like OpenSSL 0.9.8, 1.0.0 and 1.0.1, are End of Life (EOL).

Comment: PHP 5.3 is also end of life. Instead of asking around, you really should perform an system upgrade.